# include figures with multiple spaces in the filename

Tags: latex

I have lots of files with name format `case1_test     2_4.png`. For some reasons, I can not remove the spaces from those filenames. Can anyone suggest how to include this kind of file using includegraphics.

I have tried several solutions including griffle package and double quotations. However none of them works.

Tried suggestions from this page
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{spie}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\begin{document} 


\begin{figure}[t]

    \subfloat{
        \includegraphics[height=1in]{case1_test     2_4.png}
    }
    \subfloat{
        \includegraphics[height=1in]{case1_test     2_4.png}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you check that you have a space in your tex source code and not a tab? It seems strange that the code fragment in your question shows multiple spaces

Comment: can you also provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Updated the example code. I have checked the text source code. There is no tab in the file. There are five spaces after "case1_test"

Comment: Just to understand the question: does this mean there are also 5 spaces in the filename? (I'm a bit confused because the first line of your question just shows 1 space in the file name)

Comment: Yes, there are five spaces in the filename. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 4):

Using the `grffile` package and replacing the spaces in `\includgraphics` with `\space` seems to work fine for pdflatex and lualatex:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{spie}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document} 


\begin{figure}[t]

    \subfloat{
        \includegraphics[height=1in]{case1_test\space\space\space\space\space2_4}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it works on my machine as well. Where did you find the usage of $\space$?Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1784579 Normally tex gobbles multiple spaces into one, to explicitly retain them `\space` usually helps. Luckily it also worked for your file name

Comment: Ha, that makes sense. Thanks!